# Webpack Entry module not found (by tutorial)

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Found [this tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-v) (linked to last page) on codeacademy, decided to try this modern-way of deploying and configuring js apps (decided to try `ReactJS`)

Step by step implemented it just like it was told, but I edened up with this error (when I try to build everything)

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaroundapp\index.html' in
>   'C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaround'
>       resolve 'C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaroundapp\index.html' in
>   'C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaround'
>         using description file: C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaround\package.json
>   (relative path: .)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaround\package.json
>   (relative path: .)
>           No description file found
>           no extension
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>             C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaroundapp\index.html
>   doesn't exist
>           .js
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>             C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaroundapp\index.html.js
>   doesn't exist
>           .json
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>             C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaroundapp\index.html.json
>   doesn't exist
>           as directory
>             C:\Users\temp1\Documents\Learn\ReactJS\playaroundapp\index.html
>   doesn't exist

Mine `webpack.config.js`:

```
/** webpack required stuff */
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + 'app/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        minify: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: true
        },
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    });

/** thing which traces stuff and transforms in teh better way with babel(?) */
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/app/index.js',
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output:{
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },
    stats: {
            colors: true,
            modules: true,
            reasons: true,
            errorDetails: true
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]     
};
```

As well as `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "playaround",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "just test prj",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

I got no clue whats wrong here. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the path concatenation misses a slash, try

```
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
...
```

The probably better way would be, however, to use the `path` utility module (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) like this:

```
const path = require('path')
...
template: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'index.html')
...
```

This makes path concatenation less error-prone and is OS independent (backslash vs slash on windows vs *nix based os)

Comment: oh, didn't catch that one, silly me ^^
thanks a lot Matt! a slash was the case!