# React.createElement: type is invalid in simple empty app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Still struggle to just simple run simple react application (just client to play around with).

Build is ok (you can see config [here, previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303604/webpack-entry-module-not-found-by-tutorial) )

When I run server - there is an error on client side:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a
> string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in.
>
> ```
> at invariant (transformed.js:304)
> at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (transformed.js:11912)
> at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (transformed.js:27510)
> at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (transformed.js:27401)
> at Object.mountComponent (transformed.js:4158)
> at mountComponentIntoNode (transformed.js:12676)
> at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (transformed.js:5756)
> at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (transformed.js:12698)
> at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (transformed.js:5756)
> at Object.batchedUpdates (transformed.js:29031)
> ```

Here is the code:

**index.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var App = require('./components/App.js');

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='app'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {render} from 'react-dom'; //didn't helped either

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Hello React!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**FYI:**

Answer is correct, but also one thing.
Don't forget to change all `require` on `import`, like here (in `index.js`):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.js';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s telling you exactly what the problem is:

> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Change App.js similar to:

```
// ...
export default class App extends React.Component {
// ...
```

---

BTW, why are you using `require` in index.js and ES6 imports in App.js?

Comment: wellp, I am really not used to write in ES6 style, force myself to do it

Comment: but little bit different - just this `Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` not any mention of that I forgot to export smth

Comment: yep, I got in in my app folder

Comment: Then can you please try to import the App component with an import statement: `import App from './components/App.js`.

Comment: whoa, that worked out. I changed all `require` to `import`! but how come?

Comment: That's due to the way Babel transpiles ES6 modules and why I recommended you not mix them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x

Comment: oh, wow. well, thank you for the answer! can you add line about `export` as well?